# Cannot get email address when getting Teacher information from student account (OAuth scope is email ON)

Tags: google-api, google-classroom

I want to get the account information of the teacher of the course from the student's account and send the email to the teacher, or extract the email sent by the teacher from the inbox.

STEP1 GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses
STEP2 GET https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/{courseId}/teachers

```
    //response example
    {
        "teachers": [
            {
                "courseId": "1043XXXXXXX",
                "userId": "1031xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "profile": {
                    "id": "1031xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "name": {
                        "givenName": "testName",
                        "familyName": "testFamilyName",
                        "fullName": "testName testFamilyName"
                    },
                    "photoUrl": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/.......photo.jpg",
                    "permissions": [
                        {
                            "permission": "CREATE_COURSE"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
    //end

I set OAuth scopes are follows,
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.emails
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.profile.photos
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters.readonly

But teacher's profile model has not emailaddress field.
How can I get an email address?
Do I need to any configure my Teacher account?
```

Comment: For me the method returns the teacher email correctly. Have you tested it with the `Try this API`? Does it happen toy you only for one specific course / teacher?

Comment: I requested a test API(`Try this API`) using a teacher and student general account that is not GSuite.
When another member tried with an account and cource created by him(same conditions as mine), I could not get the e-mail address of the teacher account too.

Comment: And how did you invite to classroom a student from a non GSuite domain? And how does the non-GSuite student authenticate when using the Classroom API? The classroom API is intended for GSuite users.

Comment: Create and join a classroom with simply gmail.com accounts. I used the class code to join the class and run it from the Classroom screen.
I will try running it using 2 GSuite accounts they have the same domain.(But they are just  GSuite accounts, not for Education.)

Comment: I tried it with G Suite accounts of the organization and could get the email address of my teacher account.
 I will create and use a GSuite for Education test account for testing by development, thanks.

Comment: It's a safety feature that you cannot see the email of teachers if you are not in the same domain like them.